# Magento 2, How to get and set of custom_attributes value for Rest API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, custom-attributes

**API:** /rest/V1/products?fields=items,total_count,search_criteria[page_size,current_page]&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=20&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

**Output:**

```
"items": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "sku": "24-WB06",
            "name": "Endeavor Daytrip Backpack",
            "attribute_set_id": 15,
            "price": 33,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/w/b/wb06-red-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/w/b/wb06-red-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "special_price",
                    "value": "33.000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/w/b/wb06-red-0.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I want to set thumbnail url with base URL only for API. So How can I set this?

Here is my code
**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="add_custom_field_product_api" type="Ap\CustomAPI\Plugin\ProductCustAttr"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

**ProductCustAttr.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ap\CustomAPI\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductModel;
class ProductCustAttr
{
     public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $entity
    )
    {
        $product = $entity;
        /** Get Current Extension Attributes from Product */
        $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setSpecialDiscount(10); // custom field value set
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $product;
    }
    public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface $searchCriteria
    ) : \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface
    {
        $products = [];
        foreach ($searchCriteria->getItems() as $entity) {

             $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes();
            // print_r($extensionAttributes->getCategoryLinks());
            $extensionAttributes->setSpecialDiscount(1110); // custom field value set
            $entity->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $products[] = $entity;
            
            //$products[] = $entity;
        }
        $searchCriteria->setItems($products);
        return $searchCriteria;
    }
}
```

I can set the custom extension attribute value but I need to set the thumbnail image value.

Any help would be appropriated. Thanks.